# Gtk-WARNING while using gksu

Tags: gtk, gksu

When I use `gksu` I get Gtk warnings, for example:

```
$ gksu gedit /etc/fstab

(gksu:2792): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:2792): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:2792): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:2792): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

and when I close the running application instance (in this example gedit), I get:

```
(gedit:2796): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory

(gedit:2796): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.8R7MBW': No such file or directory

(gedit:2796): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are more or less harmless.

- The first one is about a missing GTK engine.

  For your specific error:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
  ```

  To find the package in error:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install apt-file
  ```

  Search for the module name that is given in your error i.e. prefix with `lib` and suffix with `.so` - so in your example `pixmap`, you need to search for `libpixmap.so`

  ```
  apt-file find libpixmap.so
  ```

  This will give the package to install e.g.

  ```
  gtk2-engines-pixbuf: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libpixmap.so
  libgtk2.0-0-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libpixmap.so
  ```
- The second one happens because the root user (`/root` directory) doesn't have a `.local` directory. You can create it by running:

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /root/.local/share
  ```