# How do i fix a "gksu nautilus" command error in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gksu, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting Gtk-WARNING while using gksu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114729/getting-gtk-warning-while-using-gksu)

When I type **"gksu nautilus"** in terminal, Im getting the following error message

> (gksu:10491): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in
>   module_path: "aurora"

I haven't a clue were to start

Comment: this is a dupe - see the linked answer now in your question.

Comment: The duplicate questions sorted me out I voted it up, sorry i missed it

Comment: no worries - glad it worked for you.